# Yii meta tags output from db dynamically

Tags: php, yii, meta-tags

First of all i want say Sorry for my English.

Site write on Yii framework. 
I have many modules, and they all have parameters "meta_keywords" in db.

In my main.php layout

```
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo CHtml::encode($this->meta_keywords) ?>" />
```

Add in my controller.php

```
public $meta_keywords = "";
```

But nothing work.

What i need to do ?

thank you for your advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , Now go to the action for eg :

```
 public function actionIndex(){
    // some code ...

    $this->meta_keywords = 'some  meta tag';  // assign values from database.

   // render view
 }
```